# Is it safe to leave the iMac turned off for months at a time?

Tags: imac, performance, shutdown

Is it safe to leave your iMac turned off for months at a time? I haven’t used it for a while, and won’t be using it for some time while in lockdown.
Will it be ok performance wise?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Is it safe to leave your iMac turned off for months at a time?

Yes, it is perfectly safe to leave your iMac turned off for months, as long you follow the proper storage guidelines, i.e. keep it in a cool and dry place and away from exposure to dust. Specifically, follow the storage guidelines laid out by Apple, as discussed here:

- [Important handling information for your Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/imac/apd876e1a2ea/mac)

> - *Storage temperature*: -40° to 116° F (-40° to 47° C)
> - *Relative humidity*: 5% to 95% (noncondensing)
>
> **Storing your iMac.** If you are going to store your iMac for an extended period of time, keep it in a cool location (ideally, 71° F or 22° C).

Storing an iMac unused for an extended period of time won't have any affect on its performance.